# Filling multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have an existing dataframe `df` as:

```
df
                        KI       Date  
DateTime                                            
2019-12-01 01:00:00    42       2019-12-01
2019-12-01 02:00:00    42       2019-12-01
```

I want to add the following table to the above dataframe while creating new columns:

```
[[1, 2],[3, 4]]
```

the final answer looks like following

```
df
                        KI       Date       col1    col2
DateTime                                            
2019-12-01 01:00:00    42       2019-12-01  1       2
2019-12-01 02:00:00    42       2019-12-01  3       4
```

I am not sure how to approach this.

Edit:

```
[[1, 2],[3, 4]] is of type numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: is `[[1, 2],[3, 4]]` a `list` or `dataframe` or `numpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
my_array = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
df[['col1','col2']] = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index,data = my_array)

                     KI        Date  col1  col2
DateTime                                       
2019-12-01_01:00:00  42  2019-12-01     1     2
2019-12-01_02:00:00  42  2019-12-01     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x=[[1,2], [3,4]]

pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data=x, columns=["a", "b"])], axis=1, sort=True)
```

(Replace `a` and `b` with your desired column names)

Comment: TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

Comment: @Zanam upgrade your pandas, you're using an ancient version. The latest is 0.25